# Easy equality with trig functions

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\gamma=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)$. I know thanks to my calculator that $2\sqrt{2}\cos\gamma+\sin\gamma=3$, however I find it difficult to show the result analitically without using a computer. The problem is therefore to show that $r=3$ in
$$2\sqrt{2}\cos\gamma+\sin\gamma=r$$
given $\gamma$ as above.
The only thing I could do through algebraic manipulation was to show that $r=\frac{9}{2\sqrt{2}}\cos\gamma$, but the main problem persists which is how to actually evaluate $\sin\gamma$ or $\cos\gamma$. Is there a way to do this and how does one go about proving these thing?

Equivalently one could show that if $\gamma$ satisfies $$2\sqrt{2}\cos\gamma+\sin\gamma=3$$ then $\gamma=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the standard definition of $\arctan$, we know that $\gamma \in \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac\pi2\right)$.

Moreover, since $\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} > 0,$ we have that $\gamma > 0$.

For $\theta \in \left(0, \dfrac\pi2\right)$, note the following identities:

$$\sin\theta = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2\theta} = \sqrt{1 - \dfrac{1}{\sec^2\theta}} = \sqrt{1 - \dfrac{1}{1 + \tan^2\theta}},$$

$$\cos\theta = \dfrac{1}{\sec\theta} = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{\sec^2\theta}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{1 + \tan^2\theta}}.$$

Now, substitute $\theta = \gamma$ in the above and use the fact that $\tan^2(\gamma) = \dfrac{1}{8}$ to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\cos x = \frac{1}{\sec x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 x}}$$ and so $$\cos \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt {1+\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\right)^2}} = \frac{2\sqrt 2}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not hard to show that:

- $$\cos\left(\arctan\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\tag1$$
- $$\sin\left(\arctan\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\tag2$$

Answer (score 1):

It follows from $$2\sqrt2\cos \gamma+\sin\gamma=\sqrt{(2\sqrt2)^2+1}\cos\left(\gamma-\arctan\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan \gamma=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}$$
$$\sec \gamma=\sqrt{1+tan^2\gamma}$$
$$=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{8}}=\sqrt{\frac{9}{8}}=\frac{3}{2\sqrt 2}$$ $$\cos \gamma=\frac{1}{\sec \gamma}=\frac{2\sqrt 2}{3}$$ $$\sin \gamma=\cos \gamma \tan \gamma=\frac{2\sqrt 2}{3}\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$2\sqrt{2}\cos\gamma+\sin\gamma=2\sqrt 2\times \frac{2\sqrt2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{8}{3}+\frac{1}{3}=3$$